# Java Thread is blocked in join()

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, blocking, notify

I have the following simple code in which I put and take from a Queue represented as an ArrayList.

```
public class EmailService {

    private Queue<Email> emailQueue;
    private Object lock;
    private volatile boolean run;
    private Thread thread;

    public void sendNotificationEmail(Email email) throws InterruptedException {
        emailQueue.add(email);

        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
            lock.wait();
        }
    }

    public EmailService() {
        lock = new Object();
        emailQueue = new Queue<>();
        run = true;
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (run) {
                    System.out.println("ruuuning");
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        try {
                            lock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (emailQueue.getSize() > 0) {
                            sendEmail(emailQueue.poll());
                        }
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
            private void sendEmail(Email email) {
                System.out.println("Sent email from " + email.getFrom() + " to " + email.getTo() + " with content: " + email.getContent());
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    public void close() throws InterruptedException {
        run = false;
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
            System.out.println("Thread will join " + thread.isInterrupted());
            thread.join();
            System.out.println("Thread after join");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why my thread is blocked in `join()` method.
From main I call as follow:

```
eService = new EmailService();
Email e1 = new Email(client1, client2, "content1");
eService.sendNotificationEmail(e1);
eService.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without running it...

- The `close()` method holds `lock` at the time it calls `thread.join()` and waits on `thread` (forever)
- `thread` is waiting to reacquire `lock` so cannot run

Both are now waiting on each other, this is a [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).  Try moving the `Thread.join()` after the `synchronized` block:

```java
    public void close() throws InterruptedException {
        run = false;
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
            System.out.println("Thread will join " + thread.isInterrupted());
        }
        thread.join();
        System.out.println("Thread after join");
    }
```

Comment: Agree, there's lots that could be done here but we have https://codereview.stackexchange.com for that! SO question is asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

@drekbour explained how your program could hang in the `join()` call, but FYI: Here's a *different* way that your program could hang. This is called *lost notification.*

Your main thread creates a new `EmailService` instance. The new instance creates its thread and calls `thread.start()` *BUT* it *could* take some time for the thread to actually start running. Meanwhile...

Your main thread creates a new `Email` instance, and calls `eService.sendNotificationEmail(...)`. That function adds the new message to the queue, locks the `lock`, notifies the lock, and then waits on the lock.

Finally, The service thread starts up, enters its `run()` method, locks the lock, and then it calls `lock.wait()`.

At this point, the program will be stuck because each thread is waiting to be notified by the other.

---

The way to avoid lost notification is, in the consumer thread, do *not* call `wait()` if the thing that you are waiting for already has happened.

```
synchronized(lock) {
    while (theThingHasNotHappenedYet()) {
        lock.wait();
    }
    dealWithTheThing();
}
```

In the producer thread:

```
    synchronized(lock) {
        makeTheThingHappen();
        lock.notify();
    }
```

Notice how both threads lock the lock. Ever wonder why `lock.wait()` throws an exception if the lock isn't locked? The examples above illustrate why. The lock prevents the producer thread from making the thing happen after the consumer already has decided to wait. That is key: If the consumer were to wait after the producer calls `notify()` then it's game over. The program hangs.